# convert oracle refcursor to text in unix script

Tags: oracle, unix, ksh

This is in continuation to the post below. I am able to return data from the oracle stored procedure to unix script. 
[Fetch data from Oracle SP Out Param SYS_REFCURSOR in Unix Korn Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273308/fetch-data-from-oracle-sp-out-param-sys-refcursor-in-unix-korn-shell-script)

But while looping through the records i dont get the expected result. Below is the code. Before the variable **table** is printed i am getting an error `"cannot open"`

```
weeknum=$1
    #read ref cursor from proc
    cur=`sqlplus -s $connection <<EOF
        SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
        var return_val refcursor
        exec WEEKLYLOAD($weeknum, :return_val);
        print return_val
        EXIT
        EOF`
    print "done"

    table=""
    while read -r line
    do
    $table=$$table"\n"$line
    done < $cur
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to direct input from your `cur` variable, but the form you are using is looking for a file with the name of the first word in `$cur` - rather than the entire contents of that variable. The error you see will be the first word in the first column of the first row of the ref cursor opened by your procedure.

So if your ref cursor was opened for a query that, say, produced three rows of output with value A, B and C it would try to read input from a file called A, and report `cannot open` (unless a file called that happened to exist in the current working directory).

You can echo the variable and pipe it instead:

```
echo "$cur" | while read -r line
do
  table=$table"\n"$line
done
```

I've removed the extra `$` symbols from the assignment. But this doesn't look particularly useful; with the same three-row result as above, `$table` would end up as:

```
\nA\nB\nC
```

If you just want to print the contents of `$cur` to the console you can use one of these (or others):

```
echo "$cur"
printf "%s\n" "$cur"
```

which both produce

```
A
B
C
```

Comment: Thanks !! it worked. This data i need to send as a mail body. So this is great solution.

Comment: Wonder how to iterate each column in a row in $cur. Hope it is out of context :)